# Using LUIS with botkit conversations

Tags: azure-language-understanding, botkit, botkit-4, botkit-middleware

I am working on a bot and I am trying to use intents instead of patterns here

```js
convo.ask('Do you want to eat a taco?', [
 {
     pattern: 'yes',
     type: 'string',
     handler: async(response, convo, bot) => {
         return await convo.gotoThread('yes_taco');
     }
 },
 {
     pattern: 'no',
     type: 'string',
     handler: async(response, convo, bot) => {
         return await convo.gotoThread('no_taco');
     }
  },
  {
      default: true,
      handler: async(response, convo, bot) => {
          await bot.say('I do not understand your response!');
          // start over!
          return await convo.repeat();
      }
  }
], {key: 'tacos'});
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [botkit-middleware-luis](https://github.com/Stevenic/botkit-middleware-luis) package. As the doc says, it replaces the pattern matching function with the returned intents from the LUIS call.

As demonstrated on the above link, you implementation would look something like this:

```js
var luis = require('./lib/luis-middleware.js');

var luisOptions = {serviceUri: process.env.serviceUri};

controller.middleware.receive.use(luis.middleware.receive(luisOptions));

controller.hears(['hello','hi'],['direct_message','direct_mention','mention'], luis.middleware.hereIntent, function(bot,message) {
    bot.reply(message,"Hello.");
});
```

Hope of help!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I have to use the intents inside the Conversations.
I have already made it work with above format but not the conversation

Comment: Note: we don't get `message` object in the conversation but only (`response`, `convo` and `bot`)